# Android Bitmap Out of memory error

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I am getting an OOM error and I need to use the entire bitmap for my algorithm to work.

Error:

```
Process: edu.illinois.ece.nano.labaware, PID: 10349                                                                                               java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 357739212 byte allocation with   3485344 free bytes and 251MB until OOM
    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:620)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:455)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1152)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:720)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:767)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:738)
    at edu.illinois.ece.nano.labaware.ViewImageActivity.onCreate(ViewImageActivity.java:69)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

---

```
50: Log.d(TAG,"Going to convert image.");
69: Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.t);
```

Comment: Really? You need a 340+MB graphic loaded into memory for your algorithm to work? Try redesigning your algorithm.

Comment: Have you tried resizing your picture to not obtain this exception?

Comment: We need more context here. You're getting an out of memory error, because you're loading a giant image to memory. This seems fairly expected. What do you need help with? Are you analysing pieces of the image independently? Are you trying to analyse relationships between different objects in the image? What alternative approaches are you considering?

Comment: I'm analyzing the RGB pixels of the entire picture.

Answer (score 0):

350+MB is just way too large to be displayed on most mobile devices. Kindly note that even if you set the width and height of a widget (e.g. ImageView) to a smaller size to show this image, the image would still be fully loaded into memory before display on the widget.

You may follow [this guideline](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap) to subsample the bitmap into the size you need to display on the screen, doing this way can drastically reduce the memory uses. If this image is required to be fully displayed in a scrollable area (e.g. a large map), you can:

1. use [BitmapRegionDecoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html) to load specific regions from that image while scrolling, or
2. split the large image into multiple smaller images, and create a html file to show the large map by combining all these smaller images and place this file and images in assets folder, and load the html file using WebView.